# WINDOW_UPDATE HTTP/2 frame

Tags: http2

At what frequency should `WINDOW_UPDATE` frame be sent by receiver?
I have test HTTP/2 client which establishes the HTTP/2 with HTTP/2 server and does Magic, SETTNGS frame (64K window size) exchange. Now client is not able to send more than 64K size data to server.

Answer (score 1):

> At what frequency should WINDOW_UPDATE frame be sent by receiver?

At whatever frequency the receiver decides. You don't have to acknowledge every message, but also shouldn't wait until the full window has been used up.

Nghttp (a popular HTTP/2 library, server and client), for example, [sends it when 50% of the window has been used up](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/master/lib/nghttp2_helper.c):

```
int nghttp2_should_send_window_update(int32_t local_window_size,
                                      int32_t recv_window_size) {
  return recv_window_size > 0 && recv_window_size >= local_window_size / 2;
}
```

> I have test HTTP/2 client which establishes the HTTP/2 with HTTP/2 server and does Magic, SETTNGS frame (64K window size) exchange. Now client is not able to send more than 64K size data to server.

I'm not surprised if the server had not send a WINDOWS_UPDATE frame to allow the client to send some more data. That's the point of WINDOWS_UPDATE frame - to avoid inundating a party who is unable to keep up. However it is up to the receiving party (the server in this case) to send the WINDOWS_UPDATE frame to tell the client it is able to send more. So this is not in your control if you are only testing using a HTTP/2 client.

Comment: Thanks Barry. Indeed server was not sending WINDOW_UPDATE so client was not able to send after 64K i.e. max buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the HTTP2 specification](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#WINDOW_UPDATE) the WINDOW_UPDATE frame needs to be sent to adjust your sending window. The initial state is described here:

> When an HTTP/2 connection is first established, new streams are created with an initial flow-control window size of 65,535 octets. The connection flow-control window is also 65,535 octets. Both endpoints can adjust the initial window size for new streams by including a value for SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE in the SETTINGS frame that forms part of the connection preface. The connection flow-control window can only be changed using WINDOW_UPDATE frames.

According to my reading of the specification you need to send a WINDOOW_UPDATE any time you'd exhaust the window buffer. This is described in an example as follows:

> For example, if the client sends 60 KB immediately on connection establishment and the server sets the initial window size to be 16 KB, the client will recalculate the available flow-control window to be -44 KB on receipt of the SETTINGS frame. The client retains a negative flow-control window until WINDOW_UPDATE frames restore the window to being positive, after which the client can resume sending.

So as a sender you need to adjust the window buffer size any time you'd otherwise exhaust the window buffer. You need to keep track of how much data you're sending and the current window buffer size and send WINDOW_UPDATE's accordingly.

Comment: I believe receiver sends the WINDOW_UPDATE frame, not the sender.